# postgresql dynamic reference to user's id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to execute a `select` statement using a for loop but keep getting an error.

`ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "my_schema"`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE schema.something()
AS $$
DECLARE
    r RECORD;
BEGIN

    for r in EXECUTE format('select * from select $1 where id=$2', my_schema.my_table_name, NEW.id)
    
    loop
      if (something = something)
          do stuff
      endif



...
...
CALL aspire.sync_demographics_ethnicity();
```

Before I used the `Execute format` I just had it like this

```
for r in select * from my_schema.my_table_name where id=NEW.id
```

But this gives me the error
`ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "new"`

UPDATE

It turns out I cannot use `NEW` in a procedure.

Is there a way I can get a dynamic reference to USER's ID? Like `NEW.id` in a trigger?

Comment: `NEW` can only be used in trigger functions. A `PROCEDURE` cannot be used in a trigger. You need to update your question to indicate what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: yes @AdrianKlaver I found that out. Would you happen to know how I can get a dynamic reference to the user's id then? I updated the question

Comment: You will need to fetch the id as an argument to the procedure.

Comment: Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: You need to provide an explanation, as update to your question, about what you are trying to do? Is this supposed to be a trigger function or a free standing function?

Comment: Its supposed to just be a stored procedure, not a trigger. I need a reference to the USER's id so I can input it in the `select` statement I have in the for loop. Then I want to update each record/row for that user. With a trigger, I can just use `NEW.id` but as mentioned, `NEW` is not avaialable in just stored procedures

Comment: I would use a `FUNCTION` as it gives you more flexibility. Then something like: `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.something(user_id integer) ...`. Pass in the `id` you want to use and then instead of `NEW.id` use `user_id` in the `EXECUTE`.

Comment: If I use a function, doesn't that make it a Trigger?

Comment: You need to spend some time with the docs, in particular: [CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html), [plpgsl](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html), [plpgsql triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html).

Comment: I am trying to avoid using Triggers, that is why I am using just a stored procedure

Comment: That is why I pointed you at the docs, you don't have an understanding of the relationships of functions, procedures and triggers. We could go around and around one line/concept at a time or you could read the docs and understand. The take away for now is you can use a function or a procedure as a stand alone 'function'. I'm guessing you will get more mileage out of a function.

Answer (score 1):

When using format() you need to use `%I` for an identifier:

`select * from %I ...`

The two selects didn't help either.
See docs here [Format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT).

Comment: I replaced with the `%` and got rid of the extra select but still getting the `missing from clause...` error

Comment: Typing mistake on my part that should be `%I` not `%1`. See updated answer.

Comment: Update your question to show the complete code you are now running.

Comment: It turns out I cannot use NEW in a procedure. I updated question

Comment: I just need a way to get a dynamic reference to users ID, such as `NEW.id` in a trigger. This is for a procedure